# TextBlock.TextWrapping - how to make the text wrap so that the lines are center-aligned?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, textblock, word-wrap, alignment

In a Windows Phone 7 application, when I place a TextBlock in the grid and set its `HorizontalAlignment` to "`Center`" and its `TextWrapping` to "`Wrap`", why does the text that overflows the width of the container and is placed on the next line, align with the left side of the otherwise center-aligned block?

Is there any way to setup text wrapping so that all of the text in the text block is center-aligned?

[image]

Comment: Also note, do not include any margins.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You are probably missing **TextAlignment**:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" />
```

HorizontalAlignment will center the TextBlock, TextAlignment will align the text *inside* the textblock.

Comment: ...and I was looking for Alignment and ContentAlignment and I have no clue how could I have missed the TextAlignment when I was selecting TextWrapping from IntelliSense... (I have one of my shaky days - I already spilled a full cup of tea all over my desk... should probably have stayed in bed this morning :-))